# Delay between .load() and $(window).bind('load')

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamically-generated, delayed-execution

I'm having a problem with a delay caused between the completion of:

```
var href = $('.mainNav').data('href');
$('#slideshow').load(href);
```

This calls up a file which only contains an unsorted list and places it as the content of #slideshow. That part is in a $(document).ready function.

The next bit of code calls the plugin jCarousel to style the content of #slideshow and is outside the $(document).ready function:

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {
  $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
```

The problem I'm having is that there's a slight delay between the list being loaded and the plugin formatting the list in which it is completely un-styled. Is there some way to make the second piece of code run before the list itself is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide it with CSS:

```
#mycarousel {
  display: none;
}
```

And then display it once the jcarousel is set up:

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {
  $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
  $('#mycarousel').show();
});
```

Also, I think it's strange that you're using `$(window).bind('load', ...)` with `.load()`, as `.load()` will not trigger a load event on `window`. Perhaps you should be using a callback for `.load()` sort of like:

```
$('#slideshow').load(href, function () {
  $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
  $('#mycarousel').show();
});
```

Comment: Did you mean visibility: hidden;? If so that didn't work, but display: none; did. Works flawlessly now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ah, yes I did mean `display: none`. Glad I could help

Comment: #slideshow wouldn't work for the .load() because it's a div I think. I read somewhere that they don't trigger load events, I just tried it as well and it didn't work. window does though, no idea.